# Saved maps in geoexplorer (geoserver layer security)

Tags: geoserver, boundless-suite, security, geoexplorer

I am a bit confused with the save maps function in geoexplorer. 
I have a vps server with the opengeo suite 3.1, I added a table to the vps local postgis db server to the geoserver.public database. I registered this table as layer in geoserver and it's working fine in geoexplorer composer. My problem is when I save the map in geoexplorer and log out and log in back (as administrator) I cannot use the query button and the edit button (they are inactive). It is working fine (so I can use the query button on saved maps) if I don't change the layer security in geoserver. But I changed because I don't want to allow to anonymous users to see any layers.

with this settings: the anonymous user cannot see the layers preview in geoserver and in geoexplorer. Admin can see every layer after logged in. But If I save the map (not publish), the query button and the edit button will be inactive.
*.*.r   ADMIN,GROUP_ADMIN
*.*.w   ADMIN,GROUP_ADMIN

with the default settings:
*.*.r   *
*.*.w   *
The anonymous user can see the layers, admin can use the query button on saved maps.

I would like to hide the layers from the anonymous users,
and I would like to use the query button on saved maps.
Is it possible to do both of them at the same time? I'm sure is possible, just I don't know how can I do that.

I cannot solve this problem and it's very frustrating. It would be great if somebody can give me some idea to solve this issue.

Thanks, 
encleadus

Comment: Is there a way to restrict add/remove layers and save maps in geoexplorer to other users except to admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, do not log in to the geoexplorer and the geoserver at the same time from the same browser... It completely confuse the privileges...